Vuforia's Area Target is always black screen
I would like to try using Vuforia's Area Target, but whether it is in Unity debugging mode or exported files, the Game window always shows a black screen. How can I solve this problem?
I tried exporting and downloading on my phone, and found that the screen was black, but my phone prompted me that the camera was on.

have you checked this troubleshooting guide? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app
